# Does updating the graphics card driver enable support of latest OpenGL version?

Tags: graphics-card, opengl

The specs for my GeForce GTX 650 say that it supports OpenGL 4.2. Does this mean that it will never be able to support later versions of OpenGL (4.4)? Or will a driver update enable support for 4.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL support relies on both hardware and software. For your GTX 650, it supports the latest OpenGL 4.5 with driver update.

[Source](https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver)